# Aggregate & Aggregate Roots

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm currently trying to define certain base classes & interfaces to use them in DDD & CQRS projects, however I'm struggling with the definition of *aggregates* and *aggregate roots*.

The *blue book* tells us that...

- An *aggregate* is a **cluster of objects**
- Each *aggregate* has a **aggregate root**
- The *aggregate root* is a specific **entity** and the only object other parts of the application can reference to.

For this, I made the following classes / interfaces:

#### Entity

```
public interface IEntity<TKey> {

    TKey Key { get; set; }

}

public abstract class EntityBase<TKey> : IEntity<TKey> {

    // key stuff, equality comparer..

}
```

#### Aggregate Root

```
public interface IAggregateRoot<TKey> : IEntity<TKey>
{
}
```

#### Repository

```
public interface IRepository<TAggregate, TRoot, TKey>
    where TAggregate : IAggregate<TRoot>
    where TRoot : IAggregateRoot<TKey>
{

    TRoot Root { get; set; }

    void Add(TAggregate aggregate);

}
```

Now, did I understood this correctly? How might a *aggregate* interface look like then?

```
public interface IAggregate<TRoot, TKey>
    where TRoot : IAggregateRoot<TKey>
{

}
```

I tried to find some references and in a CQRS framework I found the following implementation: (Does CQRS differ so much from DDD? I thought it's pretty much the same when not applying event sourcing)

```
public abstract class Entity<TAggregateRoot> where TAggregateRoot
    : AggregateRoot
{

}
```

Comment: 'Does CQRS differ so much from DDD?'. IMHO, they're completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate root is just an entity and you need not to explicitly define whole aggregate. Aggregate is a hierarchy of objects (entities and values), which can be addressed through aggregate root.

So, with your definition of `IEntity`, `EntityBase` and `IAggregateRoot` I consider:

**Repository**

```
public interface IRepository<TAggregateRoot, TKey>
    where TAggregateRoot : IAggregateRoot<TKey>
{

    TAggregateRoot Get(TKey id);

    void Delete(TAggregateRoot aggregateRoot);

    void Add(TAggregateRoot aggregateRoot);

}
```

**Aggregate root entity**

```
public abstract class AggregateRootEntityBase<TKey>
: EntityBase<TKey>, IAggregateRoot<TKey>
{

}
```

Constructions like `IAggregate<TRoot, TKey>`, `explicit TRoot`, `Entity<TAggregateRoot>` need not to be realized.

Also, please, don't overgeneralize and keep it simple. In most applications you just have to implement **one non-generic interface** for `IAggregateRoot` and **one base class or interface** for `Entity`.

Comment: Then who was aggregate? :D Let's make an example: You have a *User* entity and a *Phone* entity in your domain. Each user has several phone numbers, thus it is the aggregate for *Phone*. Does the *User* entity now contain a plain list with *Phone* numbers? What if I delete the user using a repository? Let's say I use NHibernate as my ORM.. where in the domain do I specify that when a user gets deleted, all his phone numbers get deleted too? I could declare it in the mapping configuration or in the database, however then it's not part of the domain anymore.

Comment: In your example aggregate is a group of User and its Phones (instances). Aggregate root is User, Phone is entity contained in agregate and thus it can not be referenced anywhere except User instance. Yes, of course, deleteing User instance, you have to delete its Phones. How to do that is another question. At first, you should understand that ORM defines data model, not domain model (but both models must be same to avoid model lamination). All manipultaions within data model are hided in Db Repository.

Comment: Wow, seems like I got heavily confused by ORMs,  always wondered how DDD could even work with, let's say EF because EF requires objects to have public getter/setter which might be not true for ones domain. But now everything makes sense!

Comment: Yes, today it is a bit confusing, because initial DataMapper pattern from PoEAA had to do transformation from domain to SQL. But it's today implementations (ORM) often fits bad and thus we should write transformation not from classes to sql, but from domain model to data model. If you are interested, you may look at DataObjects.net, it wants to look like Business Layer Logic Framework, and it allows to use one single model for data and domain (including ability to define fields private, etc).

Comment: @ValentinP. *"you should understand that ORM defines data model, not domain model (but both models must be same to avoid model lamination)"* This is a bit of a blanket statement. An ORM just maps between an object model (expressed in OO code) and a relational model (expressed in SQL). Whether or not you should create an additional "data model" on the object side is debatable. Can you elaborate on why you think it is necessary, since domain model and data model must, as you say, be the same ?

Comment: @guillaume31, short answer is "most ORM very often (but not always) impose limitations on implementing rich domain model, which is a principal goal of DDD". I mean for examnple problems with encapsulation, dependency injection, lots of unnecessary technical staff. Each ORM I work with has its own drawbacks. Data and domain model must be same to avoid "model lamintaion" or "layering". It's another DDD principle needed to hold model clear and maintainable. I agree that it's ok to operate with only ORM model for simple procedure-style applications. Anemic Domain Model is often about it too.

Comment: @ValentinP. I manage to have persistence-ignorant, rich domain models directly mapped by Entity Framework (Code First) just fine. And not only in procedural apps.

Comment: @guillaume31, ok, I've just mentioned that ORMs can introduce headache and restrictions is needed to be taken into account.

Comment: @ValentinP. But you sounded like having a "data model" in your OO code was intrinsically part of Object-Relational Mapping ;) Which I argue it is not -- some do it, some don't, you can map to pretty much whatever you want on the OO side.